# How to deal with fragment GET parameters in Vue Router?

Tags: vue.js, oauth-2.0, gitlab, vue-router

After trying a backend implementation of [Gitlab's OAuth](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/oauth2.html) using Web Application Flow, I'm trying out Implicit Grant in my Vue frontend.

The access code that the API sends me is in fragment url parameter format. Which means it uses the hash symbol `#foo=bar&moo=var` instead of standard `?foo=bar&moo=var` which conflicts with the default Vue Router configuration.

After trying [history mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38535565/vue-router-with-google-api) in the Vue Router, which dosent use the `#` in his urls, I can access the [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) parameter with `$route.hash`. My current problem is that I have to split and trim the parameters myself with something like the following:

```
const params = this.$route.hash.split('&').map(part => part.replace(/#/, ''));
const parsedParams = {};
params.forEach(param => {
  const parts = param.split('=');
  parsedParams[parts[0]] = parts[1];
});
```

which outputs `{ foo: "bar", moo: "var" }`

Is there a better or more standart way to deal with fragment parameters in VueRouter? If not, is there a standart solution to this outside of Vue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42309986/vuejs-get-url-query

Comment: @samayo The `$route.query` only works for parameters starting with `?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to me that my code snippet is a good enough solution, although I was expecting some support for OAuth standarts in vue. Maybe my expectations are too high?

This is what I ended up using

```
const parsedParams = {};
this.$route.hash.split('&')
  .map(part => part.replace(/^#/, ''))
  .forEach(param => {
    const parts = param.split('=');
    parsedParams[parts[0]] = parts[1];
  });
```

you can also uri decode your parameters directly from within this loop using

```
    parsedParams[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
```

Comment: thanks, although i'm not sure what is the effect of this when using hash mode with `vue-router`.

Comment: on the third bracked ending bracket is missing `.map(part => part.replace(/#/, ''))`

Comment: The `map` call removes hashes from anywhere in any name or value. To just remove the hash at the start of the string, use: `this.$route.hash.replace(/^#/, "")`

Comment: You would also want to do this: 

`parsedParams[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);`